# How to change the style of a feature collection in leaflet?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I was looking at the choropleth example.

https://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth/

This is the data source they use

```
{
 "type": "Feature",
 "properties": {
    "name": "Alabama",
    "density": 94.65
 },
 "geometry": ...
...
 }
```

My dataset is a feature collection of polygons so it looks like

```
{
"type": "Feature Collection",
"Features": [
     {
 "type": "Feature",
 "properties": {
    "name": "Alabama",
    "density": 94.65
 },
 "geometry": ...
...
 },
     {
 "type": "Feature",
 "properties": {
    "name": "Ohio",
    "density": 99.65
 },
 "geometry": ...
...
 },
   }
```

Anyway so its an array so when i make my style function I use

```
const finalLayer = L.geoJSON(currentLayer.layer, { 
style: {this.styleData(currentLayer.layer)}
           });
           this.currentProjectLayers.push(finalLayer);
           finalLayer.addTo(this.map);

getColor(data) {
return data > 1000000 ? '#800026' :
      data > 800000 ? '#BD0026' :
      data > 600000 ?  '#E31A1C' :
      data > 400000 ?  '#FC4E2A' :
      data > 200000 ? '#FD8D3C' :
        '#FEB24C';
}

styleData(feature) {
return {
  fillColor: this.getColor(feature.features[0].properties.totalHH),
  weight: 2,
  opacity: 1,
  color: 'white',
  dashArray: '3',
  fillOpacity: 0.7
};
}
```

Obviously i don't want to use 0 as the index. When I use the index it colors them all according to the index of the one spot.  I know how to do a forEach but I don't think that will work.  I need to do the style in an onEachFeature i think.... But can I apply the style using OnEachFeature.. how would I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably trying to work around an issue that does not exist.

Although that may not be explicit, [Leaflet GeoJSON factory](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.4.html#geojson) also parses GeoJSON Feature Collection, as if it were directly an array of Features. As such, each of those Features will be modified by the [`style`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.4.html#geojson-style) option, which receives as argument the Feature data:

```js
L.geoJSON(geojsonFeatureCollectionObject, {
  style: function (featureObject) {
    return {
      fill: featureObject.properties.totalHH
    };
  }
});
```

Comment: I think you are right... This works.. I actually just clicked on the example data they used and it was a feature collection ha. I think it stems from the fact that I was putting the entire layer back into the style function with style: {this.styleData(currentLayer.layer)}..Thanks