# How can I style polygons with parameters inside the FeatureCollection properties on Leaflet?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have a GeoJSON file that has both the `FeatureCollection` and the `Feature` types inside it. Basically my code is the following ([working sample here](https://jsfiddle.net/kd29mqbe/2/)):

```js
L.geoJSON(myJSON, { style: style }).addTo(mymap);

function style(featureObject) {
    return {
        fillColor: getColor(featureObject.properties.name),
        weight: 2,
        opacity: 1,
        color: 'white',
        dashArray: '3',
        fillOpacity: 0.7
    };
}

function getColor(name) {
    return name === "name1" ? "#CF8562" :
            name === "name2" ? "#FFEDA0" :
                                "#000000";
}
```

And a small sample of the structure of my GeoJSON is the following:

```json
[
  {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "properties": {
        "name" : "name1"
    },
    "features": [
      {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "randomParameter" : "text"
        },
        "geometry": {
          "type": "Polygon",
          "coordinates": [
            [
            [
            -46.6479847244904,
            -23.553060554172923
            ],
            [
            -46.6479847244904,
            -23.553060554172923
            ],
            [
            -46.64805562776844,
            -23.55318890961171
            ],
            [
            -46.64826795788915,
            -23.552928264599316
            ],
            [
            -46.6479847244904,
            -23.553060554172923
            ]
            ]
          ]
        }
      }]
  },
  {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "properties": {
        "name" : "name2"
    },
    "features": [
      {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "randomParameter" : "text2"
        },
        "geometry": {
          "type": "Polygon",
          "coordinates": [
            [
            [
            -46.648050596629034,
            -23.55393832474017
            ],
            [
            -46.64758222900779,
            -23.554141824100373
            ],
            [
            -46.64767437978837,
            -23.554322319586415
            ],
            [
            -46.64814729501603,
            -23.55411425749883
            ],
            [
            -46.648050596629034,
            -23.55393832474017
            ]
            ]
          ]
        }
      }]
  }
]
```

This code is not going to work properly because it doesn't recognize the `featureObject.properties.name` value. This value exists only inside the `FeatureCollection` and not the `Feature` type in my GeoJSON. So, I'm not capable of coloring the polygons according to the data that I have inside the GeoJSON.

I'd like to edit the style of all elements under a `FeatureCollection` type. However, when I print the object arriving on the `style` function, I see that it only sees the elements with the `Feature` type. I've read answers like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53289055) telling that we can edit the style of the `FeatureCollection` type but I didn't manage to make it work.

I'd like to solve this problem without having to change my GeoJSON structure or changing the properties inside `FeatureCollection` to `Feature`. Is it possible? Can I make the style function change the style of everything under the `FeatureCollection` type instead of the `Feature` type in my GeoJSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first loop through all FeatureCollections and copy the properties to the childs:

https://jsfiddle.net/falkedesign/9yvb46o5/

```
function copyProps(geojson, props){
    var features = L.Util.isArray(geojson) ? geojson : geojson.features,
      i, len, feature;

    if(props && geojson.properties){
      geojson.properties = Object.assign({},props,geojson.properties); // merge properties, if the feature has the same property as the parent, it will not overwritten
    }

    if (features) {
      for (i = 0, len = features.length; i < len; i++) {
        feature = features[i];
        if (feature.geometries || feature.geometry || feature.features || feature.coordinates) {
          copyProps(feature, geojson.properties);
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

```
copyProps(myJSON);
var layersObj = L.geoJSON(myJSON, { style: style }).addTo(mymap);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I think there's still a detail that's missing on your sample. One square is black and it reaches this condition only if there's no matches.

Comment: I added to the black square (now red) the property `"name": "notOverwritten"` so that you see that it not overwrites the name if one exists

Comment: Ah, I missed that detail inside the JSON! That's a cool detail. Thanks